# Space on top and bottom of image in Flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a two column flex layout with an image on the left and text on the right. Looks great at desktop size, but when it starts scaling down to my mobile break point, the image is sized down and there is "padding" on the top and bottom when I want it to take up the entire div.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F26922;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.section-v {
  background-color: #285473;
}

.flex-container-v {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-left-v {
  padding: 0px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-right-v {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 50%;
}

.content-v {
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.h2-v {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.white-v {
  color: #fff!important;
}

a .button:link {
  background-color: #F26922;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #fff!important;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold!important;
  text-decoration: none!important;
}

a .button:hover,
a .button:active {
  background-color: white!important;
  border: none!important;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #F26922!important;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes a one column-layout instead of a two-column layout */

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .flex-right-v,
  .flex-left-v {
    flex: 100%;
  }
  .content-v {
    margin: 10%;
  }
  .white-v {
    color: #fff!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section-v">
  <div class="flex-container-v">
    <div class="flex-left-v">
      <img class="placeholder" src="image.jpg" alt="placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-right-v">
      <div class="content-v">
        <h2 class="h2-v white-v">Text here</h2>
        <p class="white-v">
          text here
        </p>
        <a class="button" href="#form-section">Sign up today!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Example of what is happening on the top and bottom of the image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the margin-top &  margin-bottom from the content-v class. The text and size of the box is already determined by other CSS which has been written, so the margin top and bottom are just getting in the way on smaller browser dimensions.

```
.content-v {
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    /* margin-top: 20%; */
    /* margin-bottom: 20%; */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Below is a working version to better display the change. I added two more of the sections and a real image to better display the content.

```css
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
        }

        a:visited {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #F26922;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        .section-v {
            background-color: #285473;
        }

        .flex-container-v {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .flex-left-v {
            padding: 0px;
            align-items: center;
            width: 50%;

        }

        .placeholder {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .flex-right-v {
            padding: 0px;
            width: 50%;

        }

        .content-v {
            margin-right: 10%;
            margin-left: 10%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .h2-v {
            font-size: 32px;
        }

        .white-v {
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        a .button:link {
            background-color: #F26922;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 30px;
            color: #fff !important;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

        a .button:hover,
        a .button:active {
            background-color: white !important;
            border: none !important;
            border-radius: 30px;
            color: #F26922 !important;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        /* Responsive layout - makes a one column-layout instead of a two-column layout */
        @media (max-width: 900px) {

            .flex-right-v,
            .flex-left-v {
                flex: 100%;
            }

            .content-v {
                margin: 10%;
            }

            .white-v {
                color: #fff !important;
            }

        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="section-v">
        <div class="flex-container-v">
            <div class="flex-left-v">
                <img class="placeholder" src="https://s.imgur.com/images/logo-1200-630.jpg?2" alt="placeholder">
            </div>
            <div class="flex-right-v">
                <div class="content-v">
                    <h2 class="h2-v white-v">Text here</h2>
                    <p class="white-v">
                        text here
                    </p>
                    <a class="button" href="#form-section">Sign up today!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-v">
        <div class="flex-container-v">
            <div class="flex-left-v">
                <img class="placeholder" src="https://s.imgur.com/images/logo-1200-630.jpg?2" alt="placeholder">
            </div>
            <div class="flex-right-v">
                <div class="content-v">
                    <h2 class="h2-v white-v">Text here</h2>
                    <p class="white-v">
                        text here
                    </p>
                    <a class="button" href="#form-section">Sign up today!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-v">
        <div class="flex-container-v">
            <div class="flex-left-v">
                <img class="placeholder" src="https://s.imgur.com/images/logo-1200-630.jpg?2" alt="placeholder">
            </div>
            <div class="flex-right-v">
                <div class="content-v">
                    <h2 class="h2-v white-v">Text here</h2>
                    <p class="white-v">
                        text here
                    </p>
                    <a class="button" href="#form-section">Sign up today!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: A reminder that sharing more code goes a long way when trying to get assistance from others on Stack Overflow. While the attached image helps paint an idea of what the issue is, adding the real snippet really helps identify the issue clearly.